# Remove empty item from RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, header, telerik, row, radgrid

I have a RadGrid, which is in the first place empty (as you can see on the picture).
In order to let the RadGrid show the header without any data in the RadGrid, I needed to set:

```
ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true"
```

But the header was still not visable. After some research I found that there must be a datasource for the RadGrid, even if it's empty. So I set the DataSource of the RadGrid to a empty datatable, and that worked.
But then the RadGrid displayed a text below the header, containing: "There are no records" or something like that. In order to remove that text i've added the folowwing code to the RadGrid:

```
 NoDetailRecordsText="" NoMasterRecordsText=""
```

So now there is no text below the header, except for a small white strip, which I think is VERY ugly (see image below). Does anyone know how to remove that white strip below the header of the RadGrid?

[image: See the white strip beneath the header!]

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could easily be done using something like jQuery or just good ol' plain JavaScript, but I don't think there's a property on the RadGrid like `DontShowWhiteStripOnEmptyGrid` or anything.

Using jQuery I was able to get the white strip on [this RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx) to disappear using this:

```
$('.rgNoRecords').hide()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Haha sometimes you wish it was that simple. Now when I do that, there's a double border at the bottom of the RadGrid. I'm kind of a perfectionist, so I need to get the double to a single border when the RadGrid is empty. My JS and JQuery skills are poor, can you help me getting the double border go away when the RadGrid is empty?

Comment: Sure, but I can't recreate the problem. Do you have a proof of concept somewhere? If that's not possible, use Firebug on Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools to select the element with the border. Then play with the CSS on the right hand side to make it go away.